# Chroot Users to /opt and subdirectories

Tags: linux, ssh, chroot, jails

I'll make this short and hopefully I make sense.

Im trying to give a user ssh access, but, he/she must only be able to access `/opt` and the few subdirectories that live under it. However, here's where it gets tricky, I understand that if they are chrooted in `/opt` the other directories in there that aren't owned by root wont be accessible. That's a problem for me cause living inside there is `/opt/Pentaho` which you guessed it, is owned by the pentaho user and when you `chown root:root` that directory brings our Pentaho app to a grinding halt obviously. **SO**, is there a way for me to restrict an SSH user to `/opt` and be able to read and write files within the `/opt/Pentaho` directory or have I just lost my mind? Any insight would be great, thanks!